# Spring Security CookieTheftException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, remember-me

I am using PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices (Spring Security 4.0.3) in a Spring Boot application. Here is a snippet of the token configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
        .failureHandler(myAuthenticationFailureHandler).loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().exceptionHandling()
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(this.getOpenURLS()).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class).csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
        .and().rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices()).key(C_REMEMBER_ME_APP_KEY).and().logout();
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractRememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices = null;
        try {
            rememberMeServices = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(C_REMEMBER_ME_APP_KEY, userDetailsService, persistentTokenRepository());
            rememberMeServices.setTokenValiditySeconds((int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(2, TimeUnit.DAYS));
            rememberMeServices.setParameter(C_REMEMBER_ME_PARAMETER);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rememberMeServices;
    }
```

The configuration works as expected, the issue I have is that I am unable to handle/catch the `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.CookieTheftException` whenever this is raised. For example, since I wanted to make sure I could catch this exception, I started a session with an user, went into the database and changed the token (to a different value stored in the browser) and restarted the tomcat server. Right away when I try to access the application the `CookieTheftException` is thrown.

I have a SimpleMappingExceptionResolver Bean in my configuration like this:

```
@Bean(name = "simpleMappingExceptionResolver")
public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver createSimpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
    SimpleMappingExceptionResolver r = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();        
    Properties mappings = new Properties();

    mappings.setProperty("CookieTheftException", "cookieException");
    mappings.setProperty(".CookieTheftException", "cookieException");
    mappings.setProperty("org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.CookieTheftException", "cookieException");

    r.setOrder(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    r.setExceptionMappings(mappings); 
    r.setDefaultErrorView("error"); 
    r.setExceptionAttribute("ex");
    r.setWarnLogCategory("example.MvcLogger");
    return r;
}
```

Also, I added a @ControllerAdvice like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {

public static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "errorCookie";

@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", e);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.setViewName(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
    return mav;
}
```

}

Unfortunately, none of these are able to catch the exception. The weird thing is that if I raise the exception manually in any of my controllers the exception is successfully handled by the current configuration.

Looks like since the exception is thrown by the DispatcherServlet the @ControllerAdvice nor the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver are able to catch the exception? Am I missing something? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any help? I found a workaround using an ErrorController which checks the exception type and makes a redirect if it is the CookieTheftException but I am sure there is a better way to do this. Please, let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a long time, and couldn't find anything that made sense. As I was looking into your suggestion for using `ErrorController` as a work around, I noticed that `BasicErrorController` says this:

`* {@code @ExceptionHandler}) or by adding servlet
 * {@link AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactory#setErrorPages container error pages}.`

Since you said your work around worked, I assumed that the same errors could be caught by adding them to the servlet container with `addErrorPages`. Lo and behold in my `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return container -> {
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(CookieTheftException.class, "/login"));
    };
}
```

I just wanted users to have to log in again after this exception, so you can see I'm just sending them to the login page.